How to convert Latent heat flux in W/m2 to mol m-2 s-1 unit?
Now I have daily latent heat flux data in "W/m2" unit, how can I convert "W/m2" to "mol H2O m-2 s-1"? Regards.

To make it an interesting/worthwhile question, may be at least useful to give some background.  Some may also be interested in some further input on what your thinking towards the question is/what you've tried/if you've Googled,... though I'd think with a fair background to at least motivate the question, that could be enough.
